# How to display row value as column value in SQL Server (only one column rows value should be displayed as multiple columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Using join of parent and child tables I am getting results like this

```
  select 
      a.id, a.pname, b.childname 
  from  
      parentinfo a 
  right join 
      childinfo b on a.id = b.pid
```

Output:

```
   id   pname       childname
   --------------------------
    1   Parent1     p1child1
    1   Parent1     p1child2
    1   Parent1     p1child3
    2   Parent2     p2child1
    2   Parent2     p2child2
    3   Parent2     p3child1
    3   Parent3     p3child2
    3   Parent3     p3child3
    3   Parent3     p3child4
    4   Parent4     p4child1
    4   Parent4     p4child2
    4   Parent4     p4child3
```

But children should be displayed as columns, and one parent should be displayed only once.

And there can be any numbers of children.

I want to display results like this:

```
id  pname     child1    child2     child3     child4 
------------------------------------------------------
1   parent1   p1child1  p1child2   p1child3
2   parent2   p2child1  p2child2   
3   parent3   p3child1  p3child2   p3child3    p3child4
4   parent4   p4child1  p4child2   p4child3
```

How to achieve this? Using pivot table or any other means?

This query converted all rows to columns

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(childname) 
                      FROM 
                          (SELECT * 
                           FROM parentinfo a 
                           RIGHT JOIN childinfo b ON a.id = b.pid) tt
                      GROUP BY childname, id
                      ORDER BY id
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

    set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select value, ColumnName
            from yourtable
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(value)
            for ColumnName in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

     execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach using dynamic crosstab:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ac540/2/0)

**Generate sample data**

```
use tempdb;
CREATE TABLE yourtable(
    id          INT,
    pname       VARCHAR(20),
    childname   VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES
(1, 'Parent1', 'p1child1'), 
(1, 'Parent1', 'p1child2'), 
(1, 'Parent1', 'p1child3'), 
(2, 'Parent2', 'p2child1'), 
(2, 'Parent2', 'p2child2'), 
(3, 'Parent3', 'p3child1'), 
(3, 'Parent3', 'p3child2'), 
(3, 'Parent3', 'p3child3'), 
(3, 'Parent3', 'p3child4'), 
(4, 'Parent4', 'p4child1'), 
(4, 'Parent4', 'p4child2'), 
(4, 'Parent4', 'p4child3');
```

**Dynamic Crosstab**

```
DECLARE @maxNoChildren INT
DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql2 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql3 VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT TOP 1 @maxNoChildren = COUNT(*) FROM yourtable GROUP BY id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

SELECT @sql1 = 
'SELECT
    id
    ,pname
'

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), N) + ' THEN childname END) AS ' + QUOTENAME('child' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), N)) + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT TOP(@maxNoChildren)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM sys.columns a
    --CROSS JOIN sys.columns b
)T(N)
ORDER BY N

SELECT @sql3 =
'FROM(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM yourtable
)t
GROUP BY id, pname
ORDER BY id'

PRINT(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```

**Result**

```
| id |   pname |   child1 |   child2 |   child3 |   child4 |
|----|---------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|  1 | Parent1 | p1child1 | p1child2 | p1child3 |   (null) |
|  2 | Parent2 | p2child1 | p2child2 |   (null) |   (null) |
|  3 | Parent3 | p3child1 | p3child2 | p3child3 | p3child4 |
|  4 | Parent4 | p4child1 | p4child2 | p4child3 |   (null) |
```