# How to get row values in to columns in sql server with based on id

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following table:

```
id         Prefix     FisrtName     LastName
--------------------------------------------
123        Mr          Lynn         Berg
123        Ms          Madeline     Owen      
123        Mrs         Zelenia     Sellers  
101        Mrs         Jesse       Vincent
101        Mr          Chaim        Long
```

The result table should look like this

```
id         name1              name2               name2
-----------------------------------------------------------
123        Mr Lynn Berg       Ms MadelineOwen     Mrs Zelenia Sellers         
101        Mrs Jesse Vincent  Mr Chaim Long
```

How could I achieve this result in SQL Server? Can I use pivot function?

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display row value as column value in SQL Server (only one column rows value should be displayed as multiple columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173730/how-to-display-row-value-as-column-value-in-sql-server-only-one-column-rows-val)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple pivot:

```
declare @tbl table (id int, Prefix varchar(3), FirstName varchar(20), LastName varchar(20));
insert into @tbl values
(123, 'Mr', 'Lynn', 'Berg'),
(123, 'Ms', 'Madeline', 'Owen'),      
(123, 'Mrs', 'Zelenia', 'Sellers'),  
(101, 'Mrs', 'Jesse', 'Vincent'),
(101, 'Mr', 'Chaim', 'Long');  

select id, [1] [Name1], [2] [Name2], [3] [Name3] from (
    select id, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by (select null)) rn,
           Prefix + ' ' + FirstName + ' ' + LastName [FullName] 
    from @tbl
) a pivot (
    max(fullname) for rn in ([1],[2],[3])
) b;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do *conditional* aggregation :

```
select id, max(case when seq = 1 then Name end) as Name1,
           max(case when seq = 2 then Name end) as Name2,
           max(case when seq = 3 then Name end) as Name3
from (select id, concat(Prefix,' ',FisrtName,' ',LastName) as Name, 
             row_number() over (partition by id order by (select null)) as seq 
      from table
     ) t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
    id INT
    ,Prefix VARCHAR(3)
    ,FisrtName VARCHAR(8)
    ,LastName VARCHAR(7)
    );

INSERT INTO #Table1
VALUES (
    123
    ,'Mr'
    ,'Lynn'
    ,'Berg'
    )
    ,(
    123
    ,'Ms'
    ,'Madeline'
    ,'Owen'
    )
    ,(
    123
    ,'Mrs'
    ,'Zelenia'
    ,'Sellers'
    )
    ,(
    101
    ,'Mrs'
    ,'Jesse'
    ,'Vincent'
    )
    ,(
    101
    ,'Mr'
    ,'Chaim'
    ,'Long'
    )

SELECT *
FROM #Table1

SELECT id
    ,[1] [Name1]
    ,[2] [Name2]
    ,[3] [Name3]
FROM (
    SELECT id
        ,CONCAT (
            PREFIX
            ,FISRTNAME
            ,LASTNAME
            ) AS Namm
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (
                id
                    )
            ) AS rn
    FROM #TABLE1
    ) a
pivot(max(Namm) FOR rn IN (
            [1]
            ,[2]
            ,[3]
            )) b
```

Comment: @MichałTurczyn i have used concat function and i have give upvote for your answer